# How to handle Event of changing the object variable in JS || JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I have got variable e.g. `var obj = { foo: 'fooval', bar: 'barval'}`
How to write event and trigger to detect any modification of `obj` and then call info in console like this: `console.log('changed obj.key from oldVal to newVal')`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is new feature [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe), **NOTE** - [this feature supported only in Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-observe)

```js
var obj = { foo: 'fooval', bar: 'barval'};

Object.observe(obj, function(changes) {
    console.log(changes);
});

obj.foo = 'bar';
```

Also there are *polyfills*, for example [`Object.observe`](https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe)